# Routing to the same `pattern` but with different `args` ,`name` and `targets`

Tags: sapui5

What I am trying to do is , the `pattern` in the routing is same but the `target` and `name` are different as:

```
"routes":[
            {
                "pattern": "spec/{Name}/{Action}", //{Name}=ABC  {Action}=add
                "name": "ABCSpecificationNew",
                "target": "ABCSpecificationNew"
            },
            {
                "pattern": "spec/{Name}/{Action}", //{Name}=ABCPlus  {Action}=add
                "name": "ABCPlusSpecificationNew",
                "target": "ABCPlusSpecificationNew"
            },

            .....
],
```

I was trying to pass this way for `Name`,

```
    var routerPath=Name+"SpecificationNew";  //getting `Name` by `Id` from `view`//    
    this.getRouter().navTo(routerPath,
                {
                    Action: "Add",  Name:Name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                });
```

So from above, `Name` and `Action` are passed to pattern

```
"targets":[
"ABCSpecificationNew": {
                    "viewId": "abc",
                    "viewPath": "com.sample.view.employee",
                    "viewName": "ABCSpecificationConfigurationNew",
                    "parent": "home",
                    "controlId": "parentNavContainer",
                    "controlAggregation": "pages"
                },
"ABCPlusSpecificationNew": {
                    "viewId": "abcplus",
                    "viewPath": "com.sample.view.employee",
                    "viewName": "ABCplusSpecificationConfigurationNew",
                    "parent": "home",
                    "controlId": "parentNavContainer",
                    "controlAggregation": "pages"
                },
              .....
          ]
```

Now when I am trying to hit the `pattern` ---> `spec/ABCPlus/add`

It is routing to `ABCSpecificationNew` instead of `ABCPlusSpecificationNew`,

To my knowledge, it should match the target and route to the same ,
but this is not happening in my case.

Even though pattern here are different for both cases, it is routing to the first route.

I have no idea why this is happening , every part in the view and controller I have confirmed with no mistakes and it must have happened only in routing,

Is there a way to achieve this , any help is appreciated..TIA

Comment: Is this literally the code? Because `routerpath` should **not** be within quotes when calling `navTo`

Comment: The problem remains the same. When calling navTo, the hash will be set to `spec/ABCPlus/add` (the router knows how to build the hash because you give him the name of the route). Then the router **forgets** everything (including the name of the route) and tries to match the new hash against the existing routes. It will then see "ah, the pattern `spec/{Name}/{Action}`" matches this new hash, and the name of its route is `ABCSpecificationNew` (because you defined that route first). You **have to make your patterns unique**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curly bracket is a placeholder. The matching is solely based on the pattern. Therefore ANYTHING will match `{Name}`. Be it `ABC`, `ABCPlus`, `DEF`, `CHEESE_NUGGETS`, you name it.

When matching, the router will use the first target it finds. In your case `ABCSpecificationNew`.

If you only want to support exactly the two names `ABC` and `ABCPlus` I suggest the following:

```
"routes": [
    {
        "pattern": "spec/ABC/{Action}",
        "name": "ABCSpecificationNew",
        "target": "ABCSpecificationNew"
    }, {
        "pattern": "spec/ABCPlus/{Action}",
        "name": "ABCPlusSpecificationNew",
        "target": "ABCPlusSpecificationNew"
    },
    .....
],
```

Also if your action is always `add` (and the name and target of your route contain the word `New` it might make sense to hardcode the action also in your route definition, e.g. `"pattern": "spec/ABCPlus/add"`.

Because right now someone could type in `spec/ABC/delete` and would also land in `ABCSpecificationNew`.

Comment: edited the question on how I am trying to pass `Name` please see that , so `ABC` and `ABCPlus` are passed and the whole thing becomes as mentioned in answer!!

Answer (score 0):

As per the routing is consider same patterns will not make any sense. So my suggestion for you is to use a single pattern like `"pattern": "spec/{Name}/{Action}"` with an extra parameter which will help you to decide the type of view you want to render `ABCSpecificationConfigurationNew` OR `ABCplusSpecificationConfigurationNew.`

**Pattern**

`"pattern": "spec/{Name}/{Action}/{Type}"`

```
"routes":[
  {
    "pattern": "spec/{Name}/{Action}/{Type}", //{Name}=ABC/ABCPlus - {Action}=add - {Type}= ABCSpecificationConfigurationNew OR ABCplusSpecificationConfigurationNew
    "name": "ABCSpecificationNew",
    "target": "ABCSpecificationNew"
  } 
  .....
],

"targets":[
  "ABCSpecificationNew": {
    "viewId": "XYZ",
    "viewPath": "com.sample.view.employee",
    "viewName": "ABCSpecificationConfiguration", //single view to render the content based on the parameter Type
    "parent": "home",
    "controlId": "parentNavContainer",
    "controlAggregation": "pages"
  }
  .....
]
```

Comment: so `type` here refers to the two different `view ` names?

Comment: also , the type which we included is visible in the URL which looks bad